# python mysql function does not take some functions

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I have a python function that connects to an SQL database. I need to call some function inside the connection function, however, the connection function stops working when I put a particular function inside it. When I call fun(data) inside the dbconnect function, it does not work. Data is defined and comes from an API call.

```
seel = "seel"

def fun (data):
    di = "ImiqeleII"
    return di


def dbconnect(seel):
    rim = fun(seel)
    parse.uses_netloc.append("postgres")
    con = psycopg2.connect(database="xxxxxxx",user="xxxx",password="ad730857639e31f4dc27d11054e4759f64f02efhtfhbkjbkvf86e866872300c7f454b260ce08",host="ec2-2gcjgv",port=5432)
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO test (num, data) VALUES (%s, %s)",(56, rim))
    con.commit()
    con.close()
```

Comment: Is that your actual username and password? If so, I recommend changing immediately.

Comment: Let's just change it just in case.

Comment: Thanks for that. Noob mistake.

Comment: You tag this with mysql but you are apparently connecting to postgres?

Comment: And what is the error you are getting?

Comment: This is the error I get                                                                           
'Idling
2018-02-15T08:38:20.980424+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2018-02-15T08:38:21.819697+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM'
2018-02-15T08:38:21.987431+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved by putting the following outside the function

```
 con = psycopg2.connect(database="xxxxxxx",user="xxxx",password="ad730857639e31f4dc27d11054e4759f64f02efhtfhbkjbkvf86e866872300c7f454b260ce08",host="ec2-2gcjgv",port=5432)
    cur = con.cursor()

def dbconnect(seel):
    rim = fun(seel)
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO test (num, data) VALUES (%s, %s)",(56, rim))
    con.commit()
    con.close()
```